# Suitable Client Server setup for Network Game testing

Tags: java, networking, multiplayer, performance, testing

I want to test my Client/Server game for which, currently, I am using localhost for both Client and Server.

Obviously I'm not getting any fluctuation in data and measure idea of performance, and in other parameters, what I wanted to ask how I would test a real world scenario:

if i create a little network with two computers or

if check that on LAN on which i am or

**Are these cases (localhost included) equivalent?**

or do I really need to test my game on different LANs to have reliable and realistic testing data?

**How these different network setups influence the testing process?**

Can somebody please suggest methods for testing the effect of network latency and packet loss on my game?

**which above setup will give me more up and downs in number with LEAST setup/implementing efforts.**

The game is supposed to be played on a LAN but it IS capable of more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its hard to tell exactly what you're asking, but there's my thoughts.

When testing networking code, its perfectly acceptable to use `localhost` for both client and server to get it working, because its quick to debug and you can easily debug both client and server. It is important to note, that this is NOT sufficient for testing and final development.

In order for your testing to have maximum impact, you must test as many situations as you can. The minimum you can get away with are (IMO) these:

1. One client and server on same computer
2. One client and server on the same SUBNET
3. One client and server on the same SUBNET with additional players from other SUBNETS (Internet, etc) connecting to server via NAT
4. Server on the Internet and multiple additional Internet clients connected

Comment: thanks, i would appreciate discussion on one of the above scenarios as i have time constraints; testing on multiple/other setups would be difficult, the reason to ask question is to taking help selecting one, so i create that one setup , and then test on that. BY SUBNET you mean LAN? your  case 2 > will this be d/f from localhost and will your 2 will be different from my 2 two computer network?

Comment: If I could only chose a single scenario to test, it would be #4. Because it will cover the most bases. You will need at least two computers to test this in an accurate to the real world way.

Comment: actually the 4 is blur to me FYI the game is for LAN means not online/not http based."You will need at least two computers to test this in an accurate to the real world way" yes definitely,you didn't answer my all question, how will you take this if two computer are like this 132.145.20.145 and server 132.145.20.32, for me it's on same LAN.. DO you have same meanings for subnet, what about if my server is on 132.192.67.56 then it will be on d/f LANs.

Comment: Those IPs are routable, so in my mind, that is the Internet. What I mean. The information that you get from test #4 is that you know your application will work when its being routed. This is typically the weak link in networking code because it introduces more packet loss and latency.

Comment: what i got you mean this kind of test is enough:client 132.145.20.145  and server 132.145.20.32, (because for me it's on same LAN..) no need to go for using other LAN i.e Server is on e.g 132.192.67.56.

Comment: Ok Clear, but the setup for different LAN is difficult :-\.  Will this setup will not be sufficient. Client e.g 132.145.20.145 and server 132.145.20.32 (i.e. same LAN), what your stance on this... one more question: Do the same LAN  test can be done by this way: just my own network of two computers? or Do i use the real world LAN e.g on which i am surfing right now?.. will that be different from my two computers network? or they both will have the same effects?. please shed some light on this.

Comment: It is better than nothing. Your two computers on a single LAN is probably sufficient; you'll just need to know what depending on the network topology at your deployment site, you may see higher latency and higher packet loss.

Comment: Nothing is comparable to doing both client and server on localhost, because that is a perfect networking case. In the real world, that never happens. Testing on two different computers, connected by any network (even on the same LAN) is a similar topology to anything else you'll see. Just know that depending on setup, you'll see a wider range of packet loss and latency.

Comment: u didn't get my second question, i am repeating, what about the my network of ONLY two computers Not LAN for-example on which  i m surfing now (almost 100 PCs running with internet),that will be equivalent to localhost? =)?

Comment: If you can re-route an external port to direct traffic to your server, you should be able to connect to it from outside of your LAN. If you try to connect to it from INSIDE of you LAN using the EXTERNAL IP@, I'm guessing the packets will get no further than the router, as it should know it's own IP@.
If you want to really test, you must be outside of your LAN.
Another test would be to use Ad-Hoc WiFi connections, that can be very sluggish and have a high packet loss, which you could increase just by putting a coat hanger near your PC :P

Answer (score 2):

You can download software emulators that will artifically add packet loss, network latency, and whatever else you might like into the connection. On reflection, I actually don't know where to get these packages, but I know that they do exist.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765679/best-software-product-to-simulate-connectivity-issues-for-mobile-testing for one option which needs a spare PC with two network connections.

Answer (score 2):

**Local Host:**
All the network testing I've done on localhost has been completely misleading. Since it's a perfect environment it's useless...

**Packet Loss:**
The packet loss and latency you experience will differ based on your current lan set up. I've set up on several separate routers, and gotten completely different results.

**Recommendation:**
It would be horrifically slow to compile, throw the executable elsewhere, recompile (in the beginning, before menus and such) run it on your compie, and connect, then test.
What I've done lately is have a persistant server (on another computer) that simply forwards whatever is sent over any port to a partner, and set my program up as a client, so there's no further config necessary. It's a path that's treated me well so far.

Comment: "All the network testing I've done on localhost has been completely misleading. Since it's a perfect environment it's useless... "agreed that's why i am doing this =), im confused by these networking terminologies different subnets, LANs and now routers, no time to revised them

Comment: When you use the 'localhost' loopback the data you send doesn't go throught the entire Network Card, it stops at the Network layer and hence all the extra time needed for the Data Link and Physical Layers, and then the time needed to go through cables, etc. is obviously not represented.
If you really want to put you program through it's paces, find a helpful soul that lives on the other side of the world, and see how your Client/Server fares.